# how to create a batch file to copy files from a folder a to folder b keep certain amount of time in destination

Tags: batch-file, script

I need to create a scheduled task that copies files from a folder A to a Folder B (map drive). In the destination directory I need to retain copied files for only one month (after which it will overwrite the older files). I also want to purge older files in the source directory.

I tried using the following:

`xcopy /s c:\Folder1 d:\Folder2`

but I'm not sure about the one month retention as I have never played with this before.I know a bit about how to copy the files, but not sure about implementing the one month retention aspect. I have tried using Robocopy for this task as well.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please give a clearer description of what you're trying to do. Explain also what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: i try xcopy /s c:\Folder1 d:\Folder2 but im not sure about the one month retention i never play with this before

Comment: For this kind of operations, a more suitable utility is `robocopy`.

Comment: ok can you help me with this since im not familiar with this

Comment: Study first the documentation. But anyway, I have not fully understood your question.

Comment: what part you didnt understand ?

Comment: i will try that : ROBOCOPY *.* c:\BackupSpectro1\ k:\ /MAXAGE:30 is this make sens ?

Comment: Test using the parameter "/l  Specifies that files are to be listed only (and not copied, deleted, or time stamped)."

Comment: @PierreAuger if I understand correctly, the retention thing doesn't have anything to with the current copying. You might be able to "exclude" files older than x from the robocopy task, but the files in the destination are already there. Seems to me like you need to combine two complete separate commands, one for copying new files and the other one to delete all files older than x from both source and destinations.

Comment: Also, you use the term "overwrite the older files", but do you really mean "overwrite", do the new files have the same names as the old one in the backup?

Comment: well maybe not overwrite but copy new file and like you said maybe a separate job that delete old files

Comment: Try doing some research about "deleting files older than..."

Comment: ok thanks i will do some research.

Comment: hello i ran this robocopy command :  ROBOCOPY *.* c:\BackupSpectro1\ z:\ /MAXAGE:30 it copy files to z but not the folder inside the c: what did i miss here ?

Comment: It's really a separate question. But look into the /E and ?S switches for robocopy

Comment: ok ty i will look at that